# Excluir conta motivo conta duplicada

Tags: debate, login

estou com conta duplicada aqui no fórum e quero excluir esta, não consigo excluir e não consigo fazer logoff pra entrar com a conta correta

preciso entrar na outra conta pra ver minhas questoes, porem como loguei com esta nao consigo fechar.

Comment: Esta questão foi tratada aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1110/ - Para sair de uma conta e entrar em outra, clique no menu no começo da página, que lá tem "log out" (do lado de "comunidade atual").

Comment: Obrigado vou fazer o que consta

Comment: Tentei fazer a mesclagem porem nao consegui, na outra conta eu acesso via email e na mesclagem nao libera esta opção

Comment: não consgui mesclar divido a forma de login na outra conta uso o email e na hora da mesclagem nao aparece... meus usuários sao Ailton e Ailton Branco sendo que uma acesso via email Hotmail.com  e a outra com email Gmail.com porem os dois email tem o mesmo nome, preciso ficar com apenas uma conta qualquer uma das duas mas que seja apenas uma para evitar estes transtornos.

Comment: Solicitei à equipe de Comunidades que mescle suas contas. Por favor aguarde.

Comment: Por favor utilize a página ["entre em contato conosco"](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/contact) localizada no fundo da página, com a opção "Preciso mesclar meus perfis de usuário".

Comment: E @AiltonBranco não se esqueça que aqui não é um fórum, é um site de perguntas e respostas (Q&A)